# Set EditText as a constant n db

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, constants, type-conversion

Is it possible to take data from a edit text field and insert it into a SQLite db as a constant. I'm am trying to insert data into a SQLite primary key table and need for that data to be a constant for the db to accept it. I can't find any examples that would how me how to accomplish this.

Comment: What actually you want to achieve? I mean why do you need it? can you explain a bit?

Answer (score 0):

i gotta say, i'm not quite sure what you mean by constant. just about every tutorial advises that you insert into the database with this method:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DB_COLUMN, EtString);
    long id = db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, values);
```

EtString is the string you get from the edittext field (with .getText, .toString or otherwise). This method would also provide a id for the string in the table that you could reference. But just know that if there's an _id field already in your database table, each row of information already gets an id without you doing anything.

Here's a good tutorial for this stuff:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html